# PHP how to get the following value from class

Tags: php, class

How to get the value from class.

```
class Car {
public $model;
function car1() {
$this->model = "BMW";
}
}
```

how to get value "BMW".

Comment: PHP's manual covers objects quite comprehensively.

Answer (score 2):

well if property is public (and in this case it's public) it's very simple

```
$Car = new Car();
$Car->car1();
echo $Car->model;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you set the $model as public you could access it directly.

```
$car = new Car();
$car->car1();
$car->model;
```

but you should consider encapsulate it instead.
the better approach is to set the class variable as private and to use a setter & getter for class variables.

```
class Car {
    private $model;

    public function car1() {
        $this->setModel('BMW');
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

Comment: setters in my opinion are better when they return `$this` because you can chain them :)

Comment: @kmlnvm, I agree and I always add it in my getters, but since he doesn't know much about classes I didn't want to confuse him with returning $this.